# How can send ajax request from activex control/NPAPI and process its response?

Tags: activex, npapi, activexobject

Currently i have a wepage where I am sending a ajax request from javascript and in respose for that server is sending a video file which will be by default saved browser download location. I want the user to select download path each and every time for the file download(which can be achieved by changing browser settings which is not suited for me). So i want to include a activex object which can send ajax request and get its response. First I want to know whether is it possible, if yes is there any prototype/examples, or please let me know how it can be achieved.

Comment: Sounds like an extension may be better suited for this?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible; [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) has a mechanism called BrowserStreams that would probably work for what you're describing, but honestly I'd suggest against it.  See if you can do what you need using an extension; Chrome is dropping support for NPAPI next year and even if they weren't I think it's a really bad idea to use a plugin for something like this.

Up to you, of course.  There are examples for making HTTP GET and POST requests in the FBTestPlugin example in FireBreath.